# In Xcode, how do you set compiler flags for standalone module (framework)?

Tags: swift, xcode, blas, swift-package, swift-framework

I was writing my own standalone module and wanted to use [cblas_dasum](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1513208-cblas_dasum) for efficient calculation of the sum of absolute values of a double array. Though a message pops up saying that I have to

> specify ACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK=1 and ACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64=1 as preprocessor
> macros in Xcode build settings.

Unfortunately the function was deprecated from iOS 16.4+ (which I still need to support) and I don't see any Xcode build settings at all where to set this flag.

How do I solve?

What I see:

[image: XCode screen]

Comment: Deprecation doesn't stop you from doing something.

Comment: @matt: Doesn't deprecation mean that the method is planned to be soon removed? I wouldn't want my package to stop compiling anytime soon.

Comment: Not necessarily. Things can be deprecated for years and not taken out.

Comment: Just to give an example, `beginAnimations` was discouraged in iOS 4 and deprecated in iOS 13 but it still works just fine.

Comment: And as long as your deployment target precedes the deprecation point, you won't even see the deprecation warning.

Comment: @matt: Though I aim to support up to the latest iOS version and extend support along with the next releases.

Comment: That is irrelevant to what the deployment target is.

Answer (score 0):

If deprecated, deprecation can stay supported by the OS for years. But anyway:

## Macros

To set macros in Xcode build settings go to -> **TARGETS -> Build Settings -> Type: Processors Macros** -> Type the macro name you wish. And then set it.

[image]

## Silent Deprecation Messages

If you want to silent deprecation messages for a specific method in code, use this technique:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
- (void)YourDeprecatedMethod {
    //content...
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Try it as you need.

> #### Important
>
> Apple provides the BLAS and LAPACK libraries under the Accelerate
> framework to be in line with LAPACK 3.9.1. These new interfaces
> provide additional functionality, as well as a new ILP64 interface. To
> use the new interfaces, define ACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK before including
> the Accelerate or vecLib headers. For ILP64 interfaces, also define
> ACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64. For Swift projects, specify
> ACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK=1 and ACCELERATE_LAPACK_ILP64=1 as preprocessor
> macros in Xcode build settings.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what my XCode page looks like. I can't locate target.

Comment: looks like you've created a Swift Package Manager (SPM) project. You can only see the target if you have an iOS or macOS target. If you really want a SPM, add a device project, such as macOS. And then add this package as a dependency. If you accidentally added the SPM project, save your code, and re-create it with a device project type.  Add your code under it. And, you'll see those target options.

Comment: I've also added a screenhot.